# Cakephp can't apply a theme with auth component

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, themes

Hello i'm learning cakephp framework and i did a auth component tutorial, it worked and i can log in users but when i add cakestrap theme i got a redirection issue from chrome "webpage has a redirect loop"

This is my AppControllerClass

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $theme = 'Cakestrap';

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth'=>array(
            'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
            'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
            'authError'=>"You can't access that page",
            'authorize'=>array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
        $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
        $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
    }
}
```

thanks for your answers

Comment: You need to apply theme by using $this->layout = 'div' instead of public $theme = 'Cakestrap'

Comment: @MoyedAnsari Can you please expand upon the need of using `$this->layout = 'div'`, to set the theme name? I am coming across a very similar issue, and am having trouble understanding the need to set the layout in this manner to set a theme. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try to move   $this->layout = 'Cakestrap'; in beforefilter.